# Need help on RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I have this method which returns the **RoleDefinitionName** from a **RoleDefinitionID**

I'm getting error: RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference at the line

```cs
HttpResponseMessage RoleDefinitionNameResponse = await RoleDefinitionNamehttpClient.GetAsync(RoleDefinitionNameURI).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Can someone please help me resolve this error

```
string AccessLevel = Helper.GetRoleDefinitionName(RoleDefinitionID, SubscriptionID, AzToken).Result;

public static async Task<string> GetRoleDefinitionName(string RoleDefinitionID, string SubscriptionID, string AzToken)

{
    var RoleDefinitionNamehttpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
    };
    string RoleDefinitionNameURI = $"{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{RoleDefinitionID}?api-version=2018-01-01-preview";
    RoleDefinitionNamehttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
    RoleDefinitionNamehttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AzToken);
    HttpResponseMessage RoleDefinitionNameResponse = await RoleDefinitionNamehttpClient.GetAsync(RoleDefinitionNameURI).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var RoleDefinitionNameHttpsResponse = await RoleDefinitionNameResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic RoleDefinitionNameResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(RoleDefinitionNameHttpsResponse);
    string RoleDefinitionName = RoleDefinitionNameResult.properties.roleName;
    return RoleDefinitionName;
}
```

Comment: Well I suspect that either `RoleDefinitionNameResult` or `RoleDefinitionNameResult.properties` is null. Have you debugged through to check?

Comment: It is not getting to RoleDefinitionNameResult level in debug.
it is failing at RoleDefinitionNameResponse  line itself

Comment: That seems unlikely given that it doesn't perform any dynamic operations. It would help if you could provide a [mcve] (and ideally start using more conventional names - it's very distracting seeing upper-cased local variables).